# Hx with a PC deliberately taking harm from another PC in Apocalypse World

Tags: apocalypse-world, hx

The Harm section of the book says the following about a player character (PC) taking harm from another character:

> When you inflict harm on another player’s character, the other
>   character gets +1Hx with you (on their sheet) for every segment of
>   harm you inflict. If this brings them to Hx+4, they reset to Hx+1 as
>   usual, and therefore mark experience.

So far, so simple.

So now my question is: if PC Anne wants PC Bob to inflict harm onto her, does Anne receive the +1Hx with Bob?

Does she really learn anything new about Bob, if she wants him to do it? Or is it still worth the knowledge that, indeed, Bob will hurt her, if she wants to?

What is your approach?

Comment: I should note that this is in no sexual context where sex moves would appeal, she just wants to be shown the pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think AW rules questions can all be answered with "Say yes, roll or have a good reason for saying no." (Okay, maybe not all, but..)

Roll doesn't really apply to this situation, so is there any reason not to give those XP? As long as it's a one-time thing, and not a rules-abuse, and won't evolve into one, I see no reason why not.

Comment: To me the key question is whether the motivation is character driven or player driven. Is this the character seeking to understand the other character, or is it the player seeking leverage by manipulating the rules?

Comment: There's no way to abuse this. Harming someone is always a Move, although the MC might have to make a custom Move for consensual harm. It means something can always go wrong on a miss… And besides, the MC should be cackling in delight at the chance to make that harm really *hurt* later on. Any player that thinks this is a good way to game the system should really think twice about it. It is the very definition of handing the MC a "golden opportunity".

Comment: So this is definitely no abuse case (and I think anyone trying to abuse this is nuts for it will really hurt). Also, getting the attention of weird things via the Mælstrom is exactly what the whole thing is about. I was planning on handing XP anyways, but Hx … I'll give it to them for getting to know the world of pain that Bob lives in. :-D

Comment: Good point about something always may go wrong on a miss. Heh heh.

Answer (score 5):

I would say absolutely, Anne gets the Hx; she's learned exactly how eager or how reluctant he is to harm her.